# macro for dynamic types in C

Tags: c

When I define the macro like this:

```
    [niko@dev1 test]$ cat m1.c
    #define FL_UINT_FLINE_(N) typedef struct fl_uint_line_## N ##e { unsigned int        indexes[N]; } fl_uint_line_## N ##e_t;
    FL_UINT_FLINE_(4)
    FL_UINT_FLINE_(8)
    int main() {

        fl_uint_line_4e_t  fl4;
        fl_uint_line_8e_t  fl8;

    }
    [niko@dev1 test]$
```

it compiles perfectly. However I had to add the 'e' character ('e' for element) before and after the '## N ##' because without the 'e' I get a compile error:

```
[niko@dev1 test]$ cat m2.c
#define FL_UINT_FLINE_(N) typedef struct fl_uint_line_## N ## { unsigned int        indexes[N]; } fl_uint_line_## N ##_t;
FL_UINT_FLINE_(4)
FL_UINT_FLINE_(8)
int main() {

    fl_uint_line_4_t  fl4;
    fl_uint_line_8_t  fl8;

}
[niko@dev1 test]$ gcc -c m2.c
m2.c:1:42: error: pasting "fl_uint_line_4" and "{" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 #define FL_UINT_FLINE_(N) typedef struct fl_uint_line_## N ## { unsigned int        indexes[N]; } fl_uint_line_## N ##_t;
                                          ^
m2.c:2:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘FL_UINT_FLINE_’
 FL_UINT_FLINE_(4)
 ^
m2.c:1:42: error: pasting "fl_uint_line_8" and "{" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 #define FL_UINT_FLINE_(N) typedef struct fl_uint_line_## N ## { unsigned int        indexes[N]; } fl_uint_line_## N ##_t;
                                          ^
m2.c:3:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘FL_UINT_FLINE_’
 FL_UINT_FLINE_(8)
 ^
[niko@dev1 test]$
```

What is the correct syntax for macros in C, to make my type definitions look like this:
 (without the 'e'):

```
typedef struct fl_uint_line_4 { 
    unsigned int indexes[4]; 
} fl_uint_line_4_t;
typedef struct fl_uint_line_8 { 
    unsigned int indexes[8]; 
} fl_uint_line_8_t;
```

Comment: `#define FL_UINT_FLINE_(N) typedef struct fl_uint_line_## N ## _t ...`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added a continuation line to your macro definition so it's easier to read:

```
#define FL_UINT_FLINE_(N) typedef struct fl_uint_line_## N ## { \
    unsigned int indexes[N]; } fl_uint_line_## N ##_t;
```

The `##` operator concatenates two tokens to form a new token. Concatenating an identifier (what `N` expands to) and `{` yields something like `foo{` which is not a valid token. Drop the second `##` to fix this, it's not needed:

```
#define FL_UINT_FLINE_(N) typedef struct fl_uint_line_## N { \
    unsigned int indexes[N]; } fl_uint_line_## N ##_t;
```

Comment: This.  In fact, the GNU cpp manual says `It is common to find unnecessary uses of ‘##’ in complex macros. If you get this warning, it is likely that you can simply remove the ‘##’`

Comment: @John Hascall , I actually read the GCC manual page before I was practicing , and I saw the remark about unnecessary uses of ##, but this was helpless because I didn't know that { , [  and maybe other characters are token delimiters. The definition of token delimiter is what gcc page misses. (i am refereing to the html page about macros: 3.4 Concatenation)

Comment: @Nulik When in doubt, a space is always a token delimiter.

Comment: @Nulik This page may prove helpful https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization but the 2¢ synopsis is: `Preprocessing tokens fall into five broad classes: identifiers, preprocessing numbers, string literals, punctuators, and other. `